# Factors affecting the severity of an allergic reaction

Tags: allergy

I share a house with two very furry guinea pigs and inconveniently, am also very allergic to them. Every morning I take an anti-allergy tablet as I’m well aware that I’m likely to come into contact with the fur.

I’ve noticed the past few days that my reaction has been worse than usual, when I’ve come into contact with them. I’d normally be sniffly and sneeze a fair amount for a short while; whereas the past couple of days I’ve had a painful chesty cough in addition to this. It made me wonder, are there any factors which contribute to the severity of an allergic reaction, making a reaction worse than ‘usual’?

Comment: Well, one factor is repeated exposure.